# How to separately export a firebase cloud function 2gen from index.ts?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to update a specific cloud function to 2nd gen by following this documentation : https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta
and it says

> "Support for Environment Configuration with functions.config() has
> been removed from Cloud Functions for Firebase v2. functions.config()
> is replaced by environment variables."

The problem is, that my index.ts file exports v1 and v2 functions and I have to run functions.config() for the v1 functions.

```
export { my1GenFunction} from "./my_first_gen_function";
export { my2GenFunction} from "./my_second_gen_function";

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

...
```

However, when I try to deploy the v2 function with the `functions.config()`, I am getting a Cloud Run Error

> The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port
> defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this
> revision might contain more information.

Checking the revision log tells me:

> Error: functions.config() is no longer available in Cloud Functions
> for Firebase v2. Please see the latest documentation for information
> on how to transition to using environment variables

Is there a way to split those exports?

Thanks!

Comment: Do the terminologies "2gen" and "v2" refer to the same thing?

Comment: Yes, but I have found a solution.

Comment: Nice! You should write an answer with it. I would like to know more about it.

Comment: Actually, I was able to delete the functions.config() and the app initialized as before.

Answer (score 0):

In your code probably you aren't listening to incoming HTTP requests, do you have an env variable for the port 80? something like this:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Hello world listening on port', port);
});
```

Comment: I have found a solution, I was able to delete functions.config() and the app initialized as before